# Protractor identify Capslock is On or Off

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor

I'm using protractor to automate my application,i have a requirement where i need to verify whether **CapsLock** button is **On** or **Off**.

How to identify this through protractor?
Is it possible to do this using Protractor?

i have a secondary solution in **Java**,

```
boolean isOn = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
        System.out.println(isOn);
```

based on Boolean value i can do my operations..

but how can i call this **.class** file in middle of my **.js** file